# other fameworks similar to ajaxpro?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Just want to know if there other optional wrapper framework available that generate client side proxy js code for web methods.

I am starting development for a new website and want to evaluate a few frameworks before picking on one.

I saw AjaxPro does that , want to compare this with a few other options ( if any )
http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxPro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider [ADO.Net Data Services (Astoria)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx). This is not an AJAX framework, but it will allow you to accomplish much of what you want, and has the benefit of full framework support.

It also gives you the flexibility to use either the built in JavaScript proxy object, or you can use your own custom built stuff of your choosing, like say [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)!

AjaxPro is nice, but it will never have the same level of support that either of the two aforementioned technologies will have.